# Relative binding command with silverlight WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding

I have an error when binding my command to a button in an ItemsControl.

This is my code :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MyViewModel />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
```

with :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Test" 
                cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding MyViewModel.TestCommand}" 
                cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And I get :

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'MyViewModel' property not found on '...' '...' (HashCode=77119633). BindingExpression: Path='MyViewModel.ChooseCommand' DataItem='...' (HashCode=77119633); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand')..
```

Of course, I should use an absolute binding or a relative one, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Button` is within an `ItemsControl` which is bound to youur `MyList` property, which I am guessing is a List or some `IEnumerable` type. The `DataContext` of each `Button` will be the item within the `MyList` that it represents.

You are correct that to bind the buttons to your top-level view model you would need some sort of relative source binding, which Silverlight (3) does not support.

I created a relative source binding replacement for Silverlight here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/02/relativesource-binding-in-silverlight/

However, for WP7, where performance really matters, I would not use it!

Why not simply create the relationship you need in your view model? i.e. for each item in `MyList` (let's call them `MyListItem`), expose a property which points back to the parent view Model. In other Words, have a `MyListItem.Parent` property which points to `MyViewModel`.